# Attempt to present UIAlertController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create a `UIAlertController` in AppDelegate to handle my foreground local notifications. My code looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotificationnotification: UILocalNotification) {
    let state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if state == .Active {
        let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: "test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

But then I get this error: **`Attempt to present UIAlertController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy`**.

I already found possible solutions, but they don't work for me (`dispatch_async`, creating a `func`). I think it has something to do with the part 'rootviewcontroller', but I don't know how to fix it. Can this be fixed or is there another way to handle a local notification when in foreground?

Comment: You need to make sure that it is on the main thread anytime you modify the UI or display a new view. If you are having weird issues with it, a lot of the time dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... } will fix issues related to UI.

Answer (score 3):

So there are several reasons why you might be getting this error. I would guess that either your root view controller is not yet being displayed or your root view controller is something like a UINavigationController, which shouldn't be presenting views.

If its the latter then its really easy to fix by simply displaying from the top view controller. So something like this maybe:

```
(self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You really should keep well away from dispatch_async when performing this work, as firstly dispatching to anything but the main thread will get you into a massive world of pain (UI operations can only be performed on the main thread) and dispatching to the end of the main queue is a poor solution (if it would work at all).

Comment: I replaced/adjusted my code with your suggestion, but that is not the issue. I think it has something to do with the fact the my root view controller is not yet being displayed. But in my opinion there should be a way to display an alert in every view controller from the app from app delegate. At least that is what everybody is saying about handling an notification when the app is already running.

Comment: So your problem here is that a view controller can only present another view controller. So you can call presentViewController when anywhere you like, so long as you have reference to a view controller in the view hierarchy. So what is your root view controller? What type?

Comment: Is the root view controller the same as the initial view controller? Far as I know the only two views I have been using are view controllers.

Comment: Chances are that the root view controller is also the initial root controller (though this does not have to be the case). Basically I think the solution here is to only present the alert view when the root view controllers view has loaded. Otherwise there is nothing there to present it. To do this, I think you need to change your approach. You could post a notification when you receive this call, which a block is then attached to in the viewWillAppear function of the your controller. Or use a closure to handle the call.

Comment: Thanks to your first answer, I was able to solve the problem by first creating the rootVC. Apparently that was the problem.